# Secure way to pass OAuth tokens from iOS to server for storage

Tags: objective-c, twitter, oauth

The goal is to let users login via Twitter, get OAuth token and secret (via reverse auth) and pass it to the server. Server will then verify token validity with Twitter and create a new user as well as its own token that the app will use for authenticated communication back and forth.

I'm struggling with the latter part of this - passing the initial data in a secure way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving initial login auth the following way:

1. User logs in via Facebook or Twitter via the app (mobile device)
2. App passes device id, OAuth data to server
3. Server creates a new user based on above data (or updates current
   user using device id as primary key)
4. Server creates (or updates) user token and user secret hashes and
   returns those to the app
5. App stores token/secret hashes

Each API request from now on is signed using the user secret hash and random salt generated at request time. *User token*, *signature* and *salt* is passed along (via headers) with each API request.

Same logic is used for Socket connection handshake authorization.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, would you mind to share a sample implementation of your solution? Thanks!